# Removing white transparent space caused by Google Search Bar on the home screen after disabling Google app

Tags: app-widgets, home-screen, google-search

I would like to know how to remove this artifact of the Google Search Bar after disabling the Google app.

[image]

Possibly there is a search bar toggle in settings somewhere?

Comment: Change the launcher app. Some stock launcher apps don't allow removing the Google search widget.

Comment: What happens if you long press on it?

Comment: think changing the launcher app may be key to removing this bar

Answer (score 0):

That's the Google Search widget, but since you disabled it, it looks like a gray bar.
Just long press on it then you should be able to remove it as you would do with other widgets.

Check this video out on how to do it: https://youtu.be/Vn07c-5XcdM

Comment: this is not a normal widget because a long-press has no effect even after re-enabling the search function

Comment: I have never encountered such issue. I am not sure to be honest